# Choosing motor for a tricopter

Tags: motor

I'm a newbie in RC field..I am planning to construct my first Tricopter ever.  Can anyone help me to find the power rating to select the motor for a tricopter?

I am at the beginning stage of construction.  Arm length of frame: 50cm each.  I need a thrust of about 2Kg -- nearly 666 gms for each motor.

Comment: Welcome!  That, surely will depend on a number of design criteria, which you haven't mentioned - weight, size, power-source etc.  Could you elaborate teh question, please?

Comment: Thanks..I have added the details above. I just need the formula to calculate the power required to lift my tricopter.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you want to do with your copter.

Hovering:                              100-150 Watt/kg 
ScaleFlight:                           200-300 Watt/kg 
Some chilling acrobatic flight:        350-400 Watt/kg 
3D acrobatics                          500+ Watt/kg 
Hardcore 3D                            1000 Watt/kg

Just take the real weight of your copter, calculate the total power and divide it by 3 (in your case)

I also have a source for this but i know only a German one:
http://www.heli-planet.de/index.php?section=auslegung_von_e_motoren