# Quadcopter Propeller size + Motor

Tags: quadcopter, brushless-motor

i would like to build quad that uses bigger propellers like 15" . My question is what kind of motor shall i use ? Low or high KV? Do all motors support this kind of propellers ? Will they burn because of it ?I found they say CW and CCW motors does that mean you can't set way they spin ? I'm totally new in this so thank you for answer .

[okey so given this one it should be able to hold 15" prob since it's in description](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GARTT-ML3508-415KV-Brushless-Motor-For-Multirotor-Quadcopter-Hexa/261535221935?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D29266%26meid%3Da4bdb746beac401b8a4ca982730d114e%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D261640837515&rt=nc)
shall i get 12A ESC since on 15 size prob they used max 8.8 or shall i get 25A ESC cause max continous is 20 ?

Answer (score 2):

The Information you provide are a bit short.
This depends a lot on the power of the motors. See my answer on this question: [Choosing motor for a tricopter](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4463/choosing-motor-for-a-tricopter)

If you choose some a motor big enought for your application then it won't burn regardless of the prop size. If it is too small, it will burn regardless of the prop size ;)

Usually the motor manufactures provide you with a test sheet, something like this: http://www.funtobuyonline.com/media/wysiwyg/920_datas.jpg 
Which is one for your motor. This might be japanese (not sure) but the columns are in this case from left to right: 
Voltage,Prop Size, Power, Current, Power, Thrust, RPM, Efficency 

If the Power at 100% exceed the motor specification then the motor will burn... pretty simple