# Drone Payload Potential

Tags: quadcopter

I am new to the art of building quadcopters and am looking to build a camera platform with a payload of 250g. With the following setup would that be possible or could someone point me in the direction of calculations to find out the answer.

I have a 450 frame that weighs 363g. My motors and escs are ~200g and my flight computer and transmitter are ~20 g. And my battery weighs in at 254g

I am using 2212 brushless motors at 1000 kv. My battery is a 3s lipo with a 30c discharge rate (4000mAh) and the props I am using are 1045 nylon carbon props.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, if you need any further I’d be happy to comply.

Comment: Do the answers on [How do I work out the specifications of motors and propellers for a quadcopter?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/7662/37) not help you answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/drone-motor) link would be of some help.

The key here is to have a payload to thrust ratio of 1:2. The thrust of your motors can be found on the datasheet and also based on the power produced, the battery and the props.

Comment: Thanks that worked awesome